# dismissViewControllerAnimated not working 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Here is the scenario: I have 2 views, each embedded in a navigation controller. The first nav bar has 1 edit nav bar item, when tapped it goes to the 2nd VC. The 2nd VC nav bar has a cancel and save button, and when tapped should respond accordingly. I want to code the cancel action first, which will just call [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] but it is not doing anything...

I have also tried [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES] and neither works, please help

BTW both segues are push segues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like something off in you segues ...
i did a quick test in the following way:

1. create two view controllers in the story board ,each has it own navigation controller.
2. crate a segue from the first view controller to the second one.

2 in the first view controller  i added a bar button that preform the segue from 2.

3 to the second view controller i added a bar button with an action that did : popViewControllerAnimated:YES..

all works fine... 
though i don't really understand  why you need 2 navigation controllers here....

Comment: thanks, that worked (kinda)...I did not need both embedded in a nav controller just the first view